# "... hours he spent leisurely" vs. "... hours he spent them leisurely."

Tags: grammar, pronouns, objects

> The first two hours he spent (them) leisurely.

Google Docs suggested that I remove them in that sentence. But if I do that, *spent* doesn't have an object anymore.

Or maybe it's okay to omit objects in cases like these?

Comment: Can you give more context? @Sydney assumed, and so do I, that your intended meaning is "He spent the first two hours leisurely," in which case the object of the sentence is "hours" and we don't need the pronoun "them" because it's not replacing an absent word. But if you meant something like: "He had 100 poker chips. [During] the first two hours, he spent them leisurely," then of course "them" is the object, and is a pronoun replacing "poker chips," not "hours."

Comment: I'm not keen on adverbial ***leisurely*** in such contexts (it's primarily an ***adjective*** for me). And as [this NGram shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=left+leisurely%2Cleft+at+leisure&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), most people have always preferred ***at leisure*** for adverbial contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I checked "spent leisurely" vs. "spent at leisure". "Spent leisurely" is more common. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spent+leisurely%2C+spent+at+leisure&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspent%20leisurely%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspent%20at%20leisure%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @alexchenco: It does seem strange that your examples ***spent leisurely*** and ***spent at leisure*** should be broadly comparable (with the former becoming significantly more common just in the past couple of decades). Whereas my ***left leisurely / left at leisure*** comparison consistently shows a big preference for the latter.  Maybe I'm a bit behind the times (cut my teeth on *Victorian*novels! :) but it's certainly a bit of an eye-opener to combine *both* our search terms, and extend it back another century...

Comment: ...[like this.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spent+leisurely%2Cspent+at+leisure%2Cleft+leisurely%2Cleft+at+leisure&year_start=1819&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspent%20leisurely%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspent%20at%20leisure%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cleft%20leisurely%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cleft%20at%20leisure%3B%2Cc0) According to which, before WW2 the *only* significant version was ***left at leisure*** (all the other three virtually "flatline" until the 1930s). So I did choose a "popular" example!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'The first two hours' *is* the object. The basic sentence is 'He spent the first hours leisurely'. In formal and/or poetic writing, English allows placing the object at the front, making an object-subject-verb(-adverb) word order. Keeping 'them' means there are two direct objects, which we never have in standard English (but which is just possible in some informal or non-standard varieties).

Comment: Upvoted :) In the informal/non-standard case you might see an exchange like 
"What did he usually do when he awoke?" 
**The first two hours, he spent them leisurely. The rest of the morning, this was more productive. The afternoon, he spent that by the pool.**
(my choice of punctuation may be up for debate though)